# kv. is loaded multiple times. How to I prevent kv. from looping itself?

Tags: python, kivy

I am able to run the program but when it loads the kivy window is blank. I keep receiving a warning that the kivy is loaded multiple times. Thank you in advance.

[WARNING] [Lang        ] The file C:\Users\Eli\PycharmProjects\MedBay\mymain.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainWindow(Screen):
     pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("mymain.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ =="__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

kv file (named mymain.kv)

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
<MainManager>:
    name: "Main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "password:"
            TextInput:
                id: passw
                multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Main"
```

Comment: noted and fixed! Thanks

Comment: The code you're showing does not load "mymain.kv" multiple times.  There must be another instance in code you're not showing us.

Comment: @TimRoberts Are you getting two buttons and an input box in your kivy window? When I run this same code, my window doesn't show any boxes and I receive a warning message that mymain.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if someone who knows PyCharm could speak to whether it tries to support live reloads. Do you have the same issue running your script from the command line?

Comment: You might try something like: `kv = None` to initialize, then `if kv == None: kv = Builder.load_file("mymain.kv")` if you need to be resilient against code being rerun.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yea when I run the program via command line I still don't get any of the boxes. Also, I tried initializing kv as you did there, and still receive the same warning and no boxes in the window.  Lastly, I appreciate you helping me through this.

Comment: My suggestion wasn't quite on-point, insofar as the unconditional `kv = None` will override any previously-initialized value. It would need to be more like `if not kv in globals(): kv = None` -- though if inclement's answer is right (hopefully it is!), that still wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
kv = Builder.load_file("mymain.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
```

The App, when run, automatically loads a kv file with the same name as the app (omitting any trailing `App` and converting to lowercase). Thus, your kv file is loaded twice.

See [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv) for more information.

Comment: Hmm, ok so I would I  return pass `class MyMainApp(App):` ? I've looked at that documentation before and I am still unclear how I would directly load a file through kivy.

Comment: Don't `Builder.load_file` at all if you're going to load it automatically

Comment: so something like this `kv = ("mymain.kv")` ?

Comment: Also, how would I load `kv` automatically?

Comment: I already stated how the kv is loaded automatically, and also linked the documentation about it.